# How to change title of MDToolbar depending of MDBottomNavigationItem displayed

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm developing an app using KivyMD (at least trying). To navigate, I want to use MDBottomNavigation. My problem is that I also want to display a title with MDToolbar, "linked" to the content displayed. My .kv file looks like this :

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: blayout

    MDToolbar:
        title: "1" if... else "2"

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: navigation

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            text: "xxx"

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            text: "yyy"
```

I just don't know what to put between if and else, I think I have to check which tab is displayed (using ids ?), but I don't know how to do this and I find no clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way to do it :

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: blayout

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "1"

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: navigation

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            text: "xxx"

            on_tab_release: toolbar.title = "1"

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            text: "yyy"

            on_tab_release: toolbar.title = "2"
```